# Can we configure Visual Studio 2010 or Resharper 7.1 to create automatically empty class / function / etc comments?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, comments, resharper

currently I have to manually create an empty comment header each time I create a class, method, you name it.

Is there a way to configure a tool so it is automatically created? If possible using a tool available in our current environment:

Resharper 7.1

Visual Studio 2010

StyleCop

FxCop

Answer (score 1):

Well you have snippet that pretty much do create anything you want but it's not mind reading you still have to type some stuff. As example i created myself a snippet that on command "cmt" it write all the following automatically :

```
//**********************************************************************
//
// Created by   : Mr.X  Date: MM/DD/YYYY
//
// Modified by  :                   Date:
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Historic (Date/Description)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//**********************************************************************
```

also have a on "svcop"

```
[OperationContract]
string getX(param0);
```

I mean possibilities are endless. by default you already have alot of them there. like "ctor" create constructor of the class you in.

Comment: What I meant is that currently when I type a method Resharper tells me: "The method is missing comments" so instead of telling me that just create the default comment skeleton so I have not do it by myself every time I write a class / method / property ... Resharper knows what needs comments and what not.

Comment: I don't know how to do such thing automatically but if you want just comments on everything with mostly all completed properly i suggest you look at [Ghost Doc](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748) i use it to fill most of my function commentes and parameters but again it's not automatically done. You need to CTRL-A and right click and select "Doc this!" and it comments every Class, Methods and Fields